# "[object HTMLDivElement]" does not return my var

Tags: javascript, html, css, var

So when i run the script it shows up [object HTMLDivElement] instead of the var i assigned. The weird thing is that i did the same code on an other "index.html" and it did work. So i think it's something in the css or HTML but i can't figure out what it is.

Edit:
Here is a link for the print of what is happening.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1m7drbg4mzsxbtg/Screenshot%20%2815%29.png?dl=0

```js
var timer, s, m, h;
 s = 5;
 m = 25;
 h = 11;
function timer() {
 timer = setInterval(startTimer ,1000);
}

function startTimer() {
 s++ ;
 if (s == 60) {
  s = 0;
  m++;
 }
 if (m == 60) {
  m = 0;
  h++;
 }
 document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = s;
 document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = m + ":";
 document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = h + ":";
}
```

```css
button {
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 background: none;
}

#teste {
 font-size: 200;
}

#teste2 {
 font-size: 25;
}

.container {
 width: 1024px;
 height: 768px;
 background-color: yellow;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 font-family: Courier New;
}

 .menu {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black; 
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

  .despertador {
   width: 256;
   height: 100;
   background-color: gray;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}

  .relogio {
   width: 256;
   height: 100;
   background-color: black;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}

  .temporizador {
   width: 256;
   height: 100;
   background-color: black;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}

  .cronometro {
   width: 256;
   height: 100;
   background-color: black;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}
 .linha {
  width: 1024;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
 }
 
 .linha2 {
  width: 800;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
 }
 .content {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 648;
  background-color: #333333;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
  #despertador2 {
   width: 1024px;
   height: 648;
   background-color: #333333;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
  }
   .firstHalf {
    width: 1024;
    height: 275;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
   }
   
   .secondHalf {
    width: 1024;
    height: 374;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
   }

  
  #relogio2 {
   width: 1024px;
   height: 648;
   background-color: #333333;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   display: none;
  }
  
  #temporizador2 {
   width: 1024px;
   height: 648;
   background-color: #333333;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   display: none;
  }
  
  #cronometro2 {
   width: 1024px;
   height: 648;
   background-color: #333333;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/relogio.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="menu">
    <div class="despertador" id="despertador">
     <button onclick="despertadorButton()"><img src="imagems/despertador1.png"  width="256" height="100"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="relogio" id="relogio">
     <button onclick="relogioButton()"><img src="imagems/relogio1.png"  width="256" height="100"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="temporizador" id="temporizador">
     <button onclick="temporizadorButton()"><img src="imagems/temporizador1.png" width="256" height="100"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="cronometro" id="cronometro">
     <button onclick="cronometroButton()"><img src="imagems/cronometro1.png" width="256" height="100"></button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="linha">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <div Id="despertador2">
     <div class="firstHalf">
      <font id="teste">04:20</font><br>
      <font id="teste2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Quinta feira, 22 de outubro</font>
     </div>
     <div class="linha2">
     
     </div>
     <div class="secondHalf">
     
     </div>
    </div>
    <div Id="relogio2">
     <button onclick="timer()">start</button>
     <img src="imagems/circleClock.png">
     <font id="hours">Horas</font>
     <font id="minutes">Minutos</font>
     <font id="seconds">Segundos</font>
    </div>
    <div id="temporizador2">
    
    </div>
    <div Id="cronometro2">
    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you didn't provide the code that produced the error ` [object HTMLDivElement] ....`

Comment: This is your exact code and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/seqwqfk7/

Comment: Adelphia is rite. Your code works perfectly. I am sure there is more to your code. There is another variable name s somewhere can you please check for it. Or try renaming this s to some complex name like seconds, If you don't wish to share the full code, the only explanation is that your full code is missing and s is taking the instance of an object which is  somewhere else where in your code. And you should specifically look for div's you are manipulating (creating, editing) through java script.

Comment: Thank you  user1615664, it was a equal var from an other code. I didn't post it here because i didn't think it would make a difference. I'm a noob in javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a equal var in another code, i just removed it and it worked fine.